# Is it good practice to have gulp copy modules?

Tags: gulp-less

Should I use gulp to copy my node_modules over to my development directory? or is this bad practice? I am currently just copying them over but I feel like there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use gulp in my node projects. I think it is a perfectly good way to manage your application